# sqlite SELECT WHERE oldvalue-check,changedvalue-check

Tags: sqlite, where-clause

In a SELECT statement I change field "cat" and field "owner".
In the end of this SELECT, in the WHERE-clause I refer to the 'owner' and to the 'cat'; the values used are the original values whereas I want the original 'owner', but the changed 'cat'-value.
The statement is

```
SELECT *,CASE WHEN persoon=2 THEN catlist ELSE cat END AS cat,CASE WHEN persoon=2 THEN 'ikke' ELSE owner END AS owner FROM object LEFT JOIN list ON (id=imgref AND persoon=2) WHERE (owner=0 OR persoon=2)AND (","||cat||",") LIKE "%,aap,%"
```

It may look complicated, but basically you see:

1.in the first CASE...END how I change field cat

2. in the second CASE...END I change the field owner
3. in the WHERE-field I use owner and cat.

SQLITE uses in the WHERE -clause the original owner and cat values.
How can I refer to the changed owner or cat values?

I solved it temporarely by introducing a new field CAT2:

```
...CASE WHEN persoon=2 THEN catlist ELSE cat END AS CAT2.........WHERE .......CAT2
```

instead of:

```
...CASE WHEN persoon=2 THEN catlist ELSE cat END AS cat..........WHERE..........cat
```

but I wonder if I can say something like:

```
...CASE WHEN persoon=2 THEN catlist ELSE cat END AS cat..........WHERE.........new-valued-cat
```

Thanks for any help.................Eke van Batenburg

Answer (score 0):

2 possibilities....

1. The 2 case statements act on the same data, `persoon = 2`, this will result in a single alias "owner" and overwrite the "cat"
2. SQLite should allow alias to be used in `WHERE` clause but just in case, try replacing your alias with the `CASE` statement, if it runs correctly then you know your version doesn't accept alias in `WHERE` clause.

   WHERE (CASE WHEN persoon=2 THEN catlist ELSE cat END AS cat) = 0 OR (CASE WHEN persoon=2 THEN 'ikke' ELSE owner END AS owner) = 0 AND (","||cat||"c") LIKE "%,aap,%"

Comment: Thank you, Michelle, for your help. Unfortunately I do not understand it; why do you ask if the result of the CASE clause equals 0? Yields a CASE_AND_AS-clause any value, and if so what?
I tried your answer
SELECT * FROM object LEFT JOIN list ON (id=imgref AND persoon=2) WHERE ((CASE WHEN persoon=2 THEN catlist ELSE cat END AS cat) = 0 OR (CASE WHEN persoon=2 THEN 'ikke' ELSE owner END AS owner)=0) 
but got no records.

Maybe I made a mistake because I did not understand your point.
Nevertheless thank you for taking the trouble to look into my problem...........................Eke